# Difference between Invoice Lines and Journal Items in Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I overrided write and create functions in model : 'account.move.line'
I only want to browse the lines of Invoice Lines.
How to distinguish between Invoice Lines and Journal Items in self?
Thanks.

```
@api.model
    def write(self, vals):
        res = super(AccountMoveLine, self).write(vals)
            for line in self:
               ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In `account.move` has `type` selection field. If it has value `entry` then Odoo treats as a Journal entry. And if it has value other then `entry`, Odoo treats as a Invoice / Credit Note / Refund.

In `account.move.line` has `type_name` computed field, which set value according `account.move` type value.

Comment: if I  only want to browse the lines of Invoice Lines , should I add a condition on type ?

Comment: Yes. Correct. And Odoo has `is_invoice` function in `account.move` object. You can also use it.

Comment: class AccountMoveLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.move.line'                                                                                                      def write(self, vals):
        res = super(AccountMoveLine, self).write(vals)
        if self.move_id.is_invoice():
                for line in self:
                  ...  @Bhavesh Odedra,  I got this error  " Mixing apples and oranges: account.move.line().concat(None)"

Comment: You should check on `line` instead of `self`. And first understand is_invoice() function.